# Will an app developed in Xcode 7.3 work in phones having iOS 10 installed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I updated to Xcode 8 final release. Now, my code developed in Xcode 7.3 is throwing errors due to changes in Xcode 8. My project is in Objective C. Now if I downgrade to Xcode 7.3 then will it work in iPhones having iOS 10? Or will I have to downgrade that too to iOS 9?

Comment: Yes app will work in iOS10, just like all non updated apps work in iOS10 devices

Comment: Ok. Is there any way to use error-free Xcode 7 code in Xcode 8?

Comment: I don't understand the basis of the question.  You seem to assume that it's possible that Apple would break literally every non-updated 3rd-party app on the App Store when updating to iOS 10.

Comment: I am one project create in Xcode 7 after me upgrade Xcode 8 and open my xcode 7 project in xcode 8 and changes some in storyboard in xcode 8 that run simulator that changes view controller design changes that you are copy your old project before open xcode 8.

Comment: An update is come for more readability, improve performance and most needed User friendly ness. 
So, don't just stucked with this changes. Your project works fine in ios 10 without error.